# Change color of button programmatically

Tags: android, button

First of, I have read the multiple topics about this subject here on SO. Methods like PorterDuff colorfilter and changing setBackgroundResource. They all work but with strange hiccups that happen at complete random.

I have a button with following style (unpressed state = white, pressed = gray):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffafafaf" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dip"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <!-- SHADOW LAYER -->
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#66000000" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- CONTENT LAYER -->
            <item android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector
```

>

So to make this button green instead of white when clicked I have tried two different approaches. First one

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Than to make it go back to normal (white) I do:

```
        Drawable d = button.getBackground();
        button.invalidateDrawable(d);
        d.clearColorFilter();
```

This make the button go back to normal (white), but when I press it isn't gray (as it was before setColorFilter) but green. Somehow the colorfilter got transferred to the buttons pressed state.

Second approach. I created an additional drawable button style identical to my normal one except for item color being green (instead of white)
So with this approach I can change the button color like this:

```
b6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_button);
```

And I change it back to normal:

```
b6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_button);
```

This works as expected except for a strange behavior that happens 1/10 when I try to reset the button back to normal. The button becomes gray and it seems like it didn't read the setBackgroundResource. This happens all random and nothing in the logcat revile anything.

Please somebody help me figure out what is causing this or proposing your method for doing this. I would rather not use an imagebutton with a textfield overlapping the button with relative layout, than change color by changing imagebutton rsc. But please there has to be another way?

Comment: Please elaborate on the StateList, I find nothing on google ("android" + "StateList") about it. Some heavy reading, pskink, I try to work it trough, maybe it somehow alter the buttons pressed state with can be removed somehow

Comment: @user3711421 did you try to create a custom `StateListDrawable` class?

Comment: No, will look in to it.

Comment: @DerGolem he already uses that: StateListDrawable == <selector>

Comment: Well, yes, but it's not properly used.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate your button to force a refresh.

```
b6.invalidate();
```

That way your button should be redrawn every time.

Comment: Had forgot about trying that, nice idea but didn't word.